# Get the attribute value of q-btn

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a  component, in that I have added a custom attribute called role-id (btn inside a v-for)

```
<q-btn @click="editRole" :role-id="role.id" round color="primary" icon="edit" />
```

In this, I want to access the value inside the `:role-id` but it returns me null instead of the value

```
const editRole = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('role-id'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```html
<q-btn ref="myBTN" @click="editRole" :role-id="role.id" round color="primary" icon="edit" />
```

```js
methods:
{
  editRole()
  {
    console.log(this.$refs.myBTN.$attrs.roleId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to set this role-id, and should I set my attribute to camel case too?

Comment: I don't know where this `role` comes from - if it is an Array then you can use `v-for`. Since you have used a dash in the name of your attribute `role-id` - you can directly access it in JavaScript by removing the dash and capitalizing the immediately following letter. So you can access it in 2 ways from JavaScript - either as `roleId` or as `["role-id"]`. In HTML though, you can not write `roleId` - it has to be `role-id`. Also note that `role_id` in HTML can not be accessed as `roleId` from JavaScript.